# How to make run only a single application with all other application stopped?

Tags: applications

I basically want how to stop all other applicationa when my specific apllication is running. It's like in a BITSAT exam, when we log on for the quiz we cannot access internet and we can't access any drives of the computer.  So I bascially want that interface to work on my Android, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Development questions are off-topic but we can help you with other solutions.

Comment: In BITSAT exam, background applications still run..

Comment: sachin may b d background applications run but we cannot access them during the quiz..i want that same interface to run on android..

Comment: matthew what are the other solutions?

Answer (score 6):

This is called *Kiosk Mode* which is hot these days. Try [SureLock Kiosk Lockdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock) app. You can try searching "Kiosk" in Play Store, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Lollipop, its easy to lock down the app.
If you're on an earlier version of android, you need to:

1. Set your app as a launcher
2. Root your device
3. Hide default soft buttons

More on this here: [How-To create Kiosk Mode](https://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/kiosk-mode-on-the-nexus-7/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Android works this way.  If you have a task manager of some sort, you can shut down all open applications, but some will automatically come back.  Its just the way it is and how Android works.  Somebody correct me if I'm wrong?  And If I understand the question?

Comment: my problem statement means that the other applications may run or may not run but i want that suppose my quiz module is running so the user should not be allowed to run any other application until he gets done with the quiz. So, is there any solution to this problem.?can be either through coding too..??

Comment: not just Android, any OS made since the days of DOS are designed such that no single program can take over the system for itself at the exclusion of other programs; at least not unless you have administrator power.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such a situation, user needs to awake its developer mode. There is an option related to apps. *Background Process limit* : There you can set how many apps be in background and do you want to leave them.
**But proceed with CAUTION! on these settings.**

[image: ScreenShot of developer option related to this]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Google recently released the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) which allows to easily manage Android devices, lock them on a single application and set various other policies.