# Single application tablet possible?

Tags: kiosk-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make run only a single application with all other application stopped?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23404/how-to-make-run-only-a-single-application-with-all-other-application-stopped)

Background:

I would like to create a weather station alarm clock from an Android Tablet. This would sit on my bedside table. When I tap the screen or press the button or something, it would wake up and show me the local weather forecast.

Question:

Is it possible to make an Android tablet behave in a single application way like this? I.E. no apps, no app store, no 'slide to unlock', no other logos or screen clutter, that kind of thing?

Added:

This is more of a user interface question. I don't care if there are other applications on the device, I just want it to behave to the user as if this was a weather station device only, rather than an amazing multi-purpose computer.

I don't need it to be secure against someone who really wants to get past the main application, I just want to prevent it always annoyingly switching out of the main app. Since it's going to be a weather station only, I don't want it always offering me irrelevant things, like a handy screen saver, other apps, slide to unlock, etc. and making me have to do loads of interaction to get back to its main app.

Comment: Hopefully the other question should address this.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate, the other question specifies no internet/storage access and no way to bypass the main app.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, yes.

I would assume you could accomplish this by the following process:

1. Root the device.
2. Remap every button to the one app you want to run
3. Configure your device to operate as you want

   - remove lock screen, etc.
4. Fill in the gaps

There's where it gets tricky, you could uninstall your launcher as well, but I have not tried mapping buttons to apps (which might require a bit of custom program), and I do not know if you could get to them without a launcher installed, as that is where the system defaults to after rebooting. That being said, removing too much (like the lock screen) could de-stabilize your system, although you may be able to find work arounds for each specific issue (like using [No Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qcmFmLmFuZHJvaWQubm9sb2NrIl0.)).

This is an interesting idea, and definitely one to play around with. It could yield some interesting applications.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have added some clarification to my question.

Comment: of course! updated the answer a little :)