# Radical Android customization

Tags: customization, kiosk-mode

I have a need to setup a touch screen GUI for a booking system and I am exploring Android as a option to accomplish this.

Some crucial things I need to know are:

- Can I customize an Android based pad/other hardware so it only has on application (my booking system) running on it?
- Can I configure the booking system to autoload each time time the hardware is powered up?
- Can I install Android on a display device, like a TV, and behave like a large touch screen

All this is to take advantage of Android's powers whilst keeping the public facing booking system running continuously from power-up without other apps interfering etc.

Comment: Please, divide to 3 different questions!

Comment: Sounds like you want [Kiosk Mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23404/how-to-make-run-only-a-single-application-with-all-other-application-stopped)

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with Uwe on **#1**, it does not correctly relate to your question. What you want is only one *visible* app, so the users cannot switch to any other. That's what [Kiosk Mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23404/) is about: Creating a "jail" to keep the user in -- while the "admin" can "break it" for configuration etc. (which would e.g. require a password then). For alternative solutions on "Kiosk Mode", just [search our site for "kiosk"](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=kiosk).

Second, there are a lot of "App Lockers" and "Child Mode" apps available, which are also a variant of *Kiosk Mode*. Simply [search the Playstore for "app-lock"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app-lock&c=apps) to find a good selection.

For **#2** I must disagree with Uwe: Unless you're a developer, you cannot make "every app" a home screen (the app must register as such). But this should be handled by the app providing the *Kiosk-Mode* -- so watch out that this feature is available with that (keywords would include "autostart", "launcher" or "homescreen").

Not sure about **#3**. I know there are big touchscreens around, but I have no idea how they can be operated by an Android device. Taking a good guess, "Google TV" could be involved with that ;)

Answer (score 2):

My answers to your questions:

1. There will be more than one app running on your system because some OS tasks are also handled by apps.
2. Yes, you can make your app a home screen which will handling the start of the other apps (or not)
3. Not sure. It's possible that other devices (like TVs) are also running android.

Comment: Much appreciated