# Only give access to one application(full screen)

Tags: kiosk-mode

I am considering using tablets for use with clients at my job and I was just wondering if there is anyway to lock users into one application. Just for theoretical purposes the application could be as simple as a sign in sheet where people would check in when they come into the buildings. what I want to disable is people's abilities to get out of the application(hitting the home button, et cetera). Basically I don't want people to have access to anything besides the sign-in application.

Everything I've read points to this not being possible but I figure this is the best place to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking about is "kiosk mode".

Comment: [How to make run only a single application with all other application stopped?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/23404)

Comment: I re-tagged your question. Simply follow the [kiosk-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode) tag :)